# Cosa vuol dire "arcuofolo"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Mille anni che sto qui*, di Mariolina Venezia, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Gli operai specializzati venuti da Napoli furono alloggiati sull'**arcuofolo**, che era un piano rialzato dal quale si accedeva ai tetti, usato da sempre un po’ come ripostiglio un po' come alloggio per gli ospiti, e lí ammucchiarono tutta la loro roba, bauli lettere e fotografie, che Gioia ritrovò molti anni dopo, arrampicandosi lí sopra di nascosto alla mamma, alla nonna e alle zie.

E un po' più avanti si trova questo:

> Per le figlie Concetta trovò una pezza di velluto azzurrino, di metratura cosí ampia che fu possibile confezionare un vestito per ognuna di loro, e ne rimase ancora un bel pezzo, che andò a finire sull'**arcuofolo** in mezzo a tutte le altre cose che non si sapeva dove mettere, e fu ritrovato da Gioia molto tempo dopo, diventando a seconda dell’umore un mantello di regina, un sudario, o il mare.

Non ho trovato il termine "arcuofolo" su nessuno dei dizionari che ho cosultato. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa? Magari qualche sorta di soffitta? Immagino si tratti di un vocabolo di uso regionale, forse un dialettalismo.

Comment: Be’, non è spiegato nel primo capoverso citato?

Comment: Sì, @egreg: è più o meno spiegato lì ed è perciò che avevo pensato fosse qualche sorta di soffita. La domanda è dovuta al fatto che non ero del tutto sicura della mia interpretazione.

Comment: Forse il mio problema è che, quando leggo questo, non so se si tratta di una spiegazione di cosa significa "arcuofolo" oppure di una descrizione di com'era questo "arcuofolo" in particolare (ma forse è soltanto un mio problema).

Comment: Termine sicuramente regionale (campano o comunque meridionale). Potrebbe essere uno spazio semiabitabile che si trova fra gli spioventi del tetto.